# How to download SSL certificate and extract the public key on iOS?

Tags: ios, ssl, https, afnetworking

I'm using AFNetworking and doing SSL Pinning. Everything is working fine. Now, I need to download a SSL certificate and use extract it's public key to generate a string.

So, what I need is:

1. Grab the public key from from a SSL certificate on
   https://example.com
2. Save this SSL Certificate on my app's bundle
3. Use the public key to generate another string

Any tips?